# How do you create a primefaces confirm dialog when a row edit is about to be committed?

Tags: primefaces

I have an editable table, and I would like to know how to pop up a confirm dialog when the user submits his edits for a row. Currently, this is what I have:

This is my rowEdit listener:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update=":form1:periodBars,forecastItems" 
    listener="#{forecastTaskController.onEdit}" onstart="confirm.show()"/>
```

This is my confirm dialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirm" header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" severity="alert" >
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="confirm.hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="confirm.hide()" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

So far, what happens is when the user submits their changes, 
1. The confirmation dialog appears
2. The changes go through while the dialog is up
3. None of the buttons (including the 'x') close the dialog (In fact, the "Yes" 
 and "No" buttons aren't even clickable).

How can I fix this?

Comment: change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` and also change your dialog function code to like this `PF('confirm').show()`

Comment: Ok, I tried these changes and now nothing happens when the user tries to submit changes. No dialog appears (bad) and the changes don't get submitted (good, in a way?).

Comment: It seems that your listener is not called, could you try to debug and find that out.